# Spark UDF that returns StructType can'b be used inside select

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a UDF functions that defines schema by a version field:

```
val schemas = Map[String, StructType](("1", schema1), ("2", schema2))

def getSchema = udf[StructType, String]{(id: String) =>
    schemas.getOrElse(id, defaultEventSchema)
}
```

And I want to use this schema in spark streaming code below to parse a message:

```
data.withColumn("schemaVersion", get_json_object($"value".cast("string"), "$.version"))
.withColumn("message", when($"schemaVersion".isNotNull,
          from_json($"value".cast("string"), getSchema($"schemaVersion")))))
```

but it is failing with:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)
```

Comment: Don´t use Struct Type as udf´s return type. Udfs work in the scala types domain

Comment: I need to return `Struct Type` based on `version` field, what shall I used instead of UDF?

Comment: can you add to the question the df schema?

Comment: DF is a tuple - (schemaVersion, message)